# Getting error while running Yeoman generator

Tags: node.js, git, meanjs, yo

I was following `mean.js`'s tutorial which is at http://meanjs.org/generator.html, and while running the command `yo meanjs`  I've got the following error:

> Error: Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git --version"
>   'git' n?o ? is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

May someone provide me an explanation about why I'm getting this?

> node --version
>   
>   v4.3.1
>   
>   yo --version
>   
>   1.7.0
>   
>   npm --version
>   
>   3.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out that I had to install `git` at: https://git-scm.com/download/